# How to use mongoose aggregate well

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using this query search with Mongodb to get only '_id' value matched from 'clientID'.
 It works well at roto3T.

```
db.getCollection('orders').find({"clientID":"1234"}, {$_id:true});
```

But I want to use this at mongoose. So I put like below.
But It doesn't work well. How can I make the query search well in Mongoose?
Thank you so much!

```
await Order.find({ clientID: { $_id: true },},
    (error, order) => {
      if (error) {
         return next(error);
      }
      return res.send({order,});
},);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use Async Await,

```
try {    
    let order =  await Order.find({"clientID":"1234"}, "_id"); 
    return res.send({order});
} catch(error) {
    return next(error);
}
```

or otherwise if you want to use callback

```
 return Order.find({clientID:"1234" },{ '_id': 1 },(error,order) => {
     if (error) return next(error);
     return res.send({order});
 });
```

You can't use both to retrieve your data

Comment: Really thank you so much. And then when I use your upper anwser with async await, if the error occurs by 'Find' , catch will send the error?

Comment: Yes, it will. You can't manage error whatever you want afterward